# Pricing barrier options under risk neutral measure

Tags: risk-neutral-measure, barrier-options

I think this must be a really stupid question but I cannot see what I am missing.

Let's assume we're pricing some barrier option under Black -- Scholes model. Under risk neutral measure, the drift $\mu$ becomes the risk free rate $r$ and we compute discounted expectation of the payoff of the barrier option under this measure which is our fair value price.

Now my confusion is as follows: let's assume drift $\mu >> r$ is very large (for sake of argument), then under risk neutral measure we could be in a situation where we never go anywhere near a barrier that, under real-world measure, we would hit very quickly (with high probability). This doesn't make sense intuitively to me at all, if, say, barrier was a knock out.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: No matter what drift you assume the risk-neutral measure does not care.

Comment: The barrier option must be priced relative to the forward price of the stock which depends only on r.

Comment: If you price the barrier option based on $\mu$, it would be expensive and you could sell it versus buying the stock as delta hedge and this portfolio would make a profit

Comment: So the answer is that, however unintuitive it might seem, there is nothing special about barrier options and we still evaluate whether barrier has been hit using Brownian paths with drift $r$ (e.g. if doing MC)?

Comment: Yes indeed correct

Comment: The real problem with barrier options is that they are sensitive to skew and smile in the vol. So the Black-Scholes model is inappropriate to price them. You need stochastic vol or a local vol model.

Comment: Which only tells you that the risk-neutral price of something like [knockout](http://stanfordphd.com/Knockout_Option.html) can be quite different from the discounted real-measure expectation.